# Confusion about how Java deals with aggregation and referencing

Tags: java, reference, aggregation

I am confused about how Java deals with aggregation within objects, and in particular referencing of objects. It seems like objects will keep a reference to an aggregated object when it is passed as a parameter, rather than copying it like I've been lead to believe.

Say I have a basic class called Foo which contains a string attribute, print function, and setter for the text attribute.

```
public class Foo {

    private String text;

    public Foo(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

And a class called Bar which contains an attribute of type Foo, and a method called print which calls foos print method.

```
public class Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void print() {
        this.foo.print();
    }

}
```

If I define an instance of Foo, pass it into a new instance of Bar, and then call bars print method it will print "hello" as I expected. However if I then set the text of the original instance of foo to "Edited" using its setter method, bars print method will also print "Edited".

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Foo foo = new Foo("Hello");
    Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
    bar.print();
    foo.setText("Edited");
    bar.print();

}
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQhrv.png)

The Bar object appears to be keeping a reference to the Foo object even though I passed it as a parameter. I'm sure I am missing something trivial here, and I just wanted someone to explain this clearly.

Comment: *rather than copying it like I've been lead to believe.* Why have you been lead to believe **that**? Java does not perform deep copies of parameters.

Comment: *"... rather than copying it like I've been lead to believe."* You've been misled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reference copied, not object

> It seems like objects will keep a reference to an aggregated object when it is passed as a parameter, rather than copying it like I've been lead to believe.

No, **the object is *not* copied**.

The reference (pointer) is copied when passed as an argument to a method. The object (the referent, the thing to which the pointer points) is *not* copied.

The pointer is really an address in memory someplace (though not seen as such by us Java programmers). That address, basically a number, is being copied when passed into the other method. But the object is left untouched, unaware of any references.

Here's a diagram of several `Cat` objects in memory. Three of the five are candidates for [garbage-collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) because they have no references remaining, no pointers pointing to them. At first `Lilly Mae` cat has one pointer pointing to it.

```
Cat c = new Cat( "Lilly Mae" ) ;
```

The `c` variable is *not* holding a `Cat`, it holds the address elsewhere in memory where you can find the `Cat` object. Think of that line as saying:

```
variable-holding-pointer-that-can-only-point-to-objects-of-class-Cat c = instantiate-new-object-of-type-Cat-and-return-a-pointer-to-its-location-in-memory( "Lilly Mae" ) ;
```

Then we pass that pointer as a argument to another method.

```
Human h = SubservientHumanLocator.findFirstAvailable() ;
h.feedCat( c ) ;  // Passing a copy of the address of Lilly Mae to this other object’s method.
```

After the reference to the `Cat` is passed to the `Human`, we still have only one hungry cat. We did not clone the cat. We now have *two* references, both pointing to same original `Cat` object.

Here is a diagram of state before and after the `Human::feedCat` call.

[image]

After calling on the human to feed the cat, the variable `c` may fall out of scope. After feeding the cat, the `Human` object `h` will likely let its copied reference also fall out of scope. Then, if no other references had been made, and with no existing references remaining, our well-fed `Cat` object will become a candidate for garbage-collection.

Comment: Thank you, that was a clear explanation and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm sure I am missing something trivial here"

Not really.  What you see is not a bug, it is a feature.  Passing objects around in java means passing around ***references to them***.  Objects aren't "cloned" unless the code explicitly requests this through .clone().  Searching on this site for "is java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference" should help you find all the detailed explanation you need.

Comment: A feature that I frequently use. I didn't know about .clone() though, thanks. What is the meaning of "pass by value" then?

Comment: @Max As suggested by the Answer, search Stack Overflow for those technical phrases *pass-by-value* and *pass-by-reference*. They have been covered many times already. No point in rehashing them here.